# sorting JavaScript array that contains version numbers and letters (where letters represents a numerical value)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Say I have an array like this:

```
input = [
    "1.1",
    "1.c",
    "1.b",
    "1",
    "D",
    "b",
    "4",
    "2.1.2",
    "5.1",
    "3",
    "2.a.1"
]
```

What would be the best way to sort this and get result like this:

```
sorted = [
    "1",
    "1.1",
    "1.b",
    "1.c",
    "b",
    "2.a.1",
    "2.1.2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "D",
    "5.1"
]
```

Here, to sort, consider:

***'a' or 'A' is equivalent to 1,***

***'b' or 'B' is equivalent to 2,***

and so on.

The array contains numbers and letters only, no symbols.

**So far I have tried:**

```js
input = ["1", "1.1", "1.b", "1.c", "b", "2.a.1", "2.1.2", "3", "4", "D", "5.1"]
console.log(input.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)));
```

Does not give me the desired result. Need help on it.
Any suggestions, please?

Comment: You can use the sort() method to sort an array in JavaScript, but it sorts elements in lexicographic order by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a function to transform the inputs and the sort function. Here is how I did it:

```js
input = [
    "1.1",
    "1.c",
    "1.b",
    "1",
    "D",
    "b",
    "4",
    "2.1.2",
    "5.1",
    "3",
    "2.a.1"
]

function convert(el){
 const nums = el.split(".");
 return nums.map(n => {
    if(n.match(/[A-z]/)){ 
      return n.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 96;
    }
    return n;
  }).join(".");
}

input.sort((a,b) => {
  const convA = convert(a);
  const convB = convert(b);
  return convA.localeCompare(convB);
})

console.log(input);
```

Comment: Your code is great but we could also do the following for the convert

function convert(el){
      const lowerCased = el.toLowerCase();
      let key = "";
      for (const c of lowerCased) {
      key += (c.charCodeAt(0) >= 97 && c.charCodeAt(0) <= 122) ? c.charCodeAt(0) - 96 : c;
     return key;
}

Comment: Yes It can be simplified but I was trying to make it super simple to understand. But yes your solution is more compact.

Comment: I think yours is clearer, great solution!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplified version of @mgm793's sort function:

```js
input = [
    "1.1",
    "1.c",
    "1.b",
    "1",
    "D",
    "b",
    "4",
    "2.1.2",
    "5.1",
    "3",
    "2.a.1"
]

function conv(str){
 return str.toLowerCase().replace(/[a-z]/g,m=>m.charCodeAt(0)-96)
}

input.sort((a,b) =>conv(a).localeCompare(conv(b)))

console.log(input);
```

And here is another version that will also be stable for higher numbers (up to `26`) and letters (up to `z`):

```js
input = [
    "1.10",
    "1.m",
    "1.b",
    "1.1.3",
    "1",
    "F",
    "b",
    "4",
    "2.1.2",
    "5.1",
    "3",
    "2.a.1"
]

let res=input.map(e=>[e.toLowerCase().replace(/\d+/g,m=>String.fromCharCode(+m+96)),e])
             .sort(([a],[b])=>a.localeCompare(b))
             .map(([_,e])=>e);

console.log(res);
```

This snippet converts every number and every combination of digits and letters to a string consisting only of characters (`a` to `z`) and dots (`.`). These strings can easily be sorted using `String.localeCompare()`. They are combined with the original values into a temporary array. This array is then sorted and the original values are taken from it again in a final `.map()` loop. As a side effect of this approach the original array (`input`) remains unchanged while `res` becomes the sorted version of it.